# char array split ip with strtok

Tags: c

I'm trying to split a IP address like 127.0.0.1 from a file:

using following C code:

```
pch2 = strtok (ip,".");
printf("\npart 1 ip: %s",pch2);
pch2 = strtok (NULL,".");
printf("\npart 2 ip: %s",pch2);
```

And IP is a char ip[500], that containt an ip.

When printing it prints 127 as part 1 but as part 2 it prints NULL?

Can someone help me?

EDIT:

Whole function:

```
FILE *file = fopen ("host.txt", "r");
char * pch;
char * pch2;
char ip[BUFFSIZE];
IPPart result;

if (file != NULL)
{
    char line [BUFFSIZE]; 
    while(fgets(line,sizeof line,file) != NULL)
    {
        if(line[0] != '#')
        {
                            pch = strtok (line," ");
            printf ("%s\n",pch);

            strncpy(ip, pch, strlen(pch)-1);
            ip[sizeof(pch)-1] = '\0';

            //pch = strtok (line, " ");
            pch = strtok (NULL," ");
            printf("%s",pch);


            pch2 = strtok (ip,".");
            printf("\nDeel 1 ip: %s",pch2);
            pch2 = strtok (NULL,".");
            printf("\nDeel 2 ip: %s",pch2);
            pch2 = strtok(NULL,".");
            printf("\nDeel 3 ip: %s",pch2);
            pch2 = strtok(NULL,".");
            printf("\nDeel 4 ip: %s",pch2);

        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I can't reproduce the error. Try to show the initialization of ip.

Comment: how can it **print** `NULL`? Are you sure about the problem?

Comment: I've added the whole code, i'm reading something like a host file. Don't know how it can print null...:s

Comment: @Aniket: `printf()` seems to print the string `"(null)"` if a null char pointer is provided with the `%s` specifier, but it can be non-standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do a

```
strncpy(ip, pch, sizeof(pch) - 1);
ip[sizeof(pch)-1] = '\0';
```

This should be

```
strncpy(ip, pch, strlen(pch));
ip[strlen(pch)] = '\0';
```

or better yet, just

```
strcpy(ip, pch);
```

because `sizeof(pch) - 1` is `sizeof(char*) - 1`, which is just 3 bytes on a 32 bit machine. This corresponds to 3 chars, namely "127", which is in line with your observation the second `strtok()` giving NULL.

Comment: @user1480139 Please see the modified answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used your code as following and it works for me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char ip[500] = "127.0.0.1";

int main() {
    char *pch2;
    pch2 = strtok (ip,".");
    printf("\npart 1 ip: %s",pch2);
    pch2 = strtok (NULL,".");
    printf("\npart 2 ip: %s",pch2);
    return 0; 
}
```

execution

```
linux$ gcc -o test test.c
linux$ ./test

part 1 ip: 127
part 2 ip: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, Visual studio adds the 0 to the pointer and thats the same as NULL ...

Comment: Please see my answer as well.

Comment: I thought I found it with my test but It doens't work. I edited the code lik eyou said, still prints NULL